# Django Selenium LiveServerTestCase not loading the page in browser (error 500)

Tags: django, selenium

I have a test Django project called MyApp, running over WSGI on port 8083. When I go to `http://myapp:8083`, I see the standard Django "it's working" page. I wrote a functional test using selenium bindings in Django to launch a browser and load the above mentioned page. When I run the test, though, I get an error message "Address already in use". So I run the test using another port like this: `python manage.py test --liveserver=myapp:8084`

This opens the browser, but shows "Page not found" error instead of the default Django page. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas? Thank you!

The test.py file content:

```
class CoreSeleniumTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        super(CoreSeleniumTestCase, cls).setUpClass()


    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
        super(CoreSeleniumTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()


    def testIndexShouldLoad(self):
        self.driver.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/'))
```

Comment: Print out the value of `self.live_server_url` before getting the page in `testIndexShouldLoad` method. What is the value?

Comment: I printed it out and the value is `http://myapp:8084`. When I execute the tests using `python manage.py test` (not specifying a custom liveserver port), it attempts to open `http://myapp:8083` and gives an error of "Address already in use".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. At some point, Django removed MEDIA_ROOT from the settings.py file by default. It turns out that this setting must be in the file for Selenium tests to work properly. Once I reintroduced the setting and assigned a directory to it, the Selenium tests started to work as expected.